# How to replace slice of bytes with slice of bytes?

Tags: solidity, assembly

This is related to this question here: [Solidity: how to replace slices of bytes with assembly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/132100/solidity-how-to-replace-slices-of-bytes-with-assembly/132110?noredirect=1#comment153060_132110)

Although with one extra part: I'd like to be able to replacement with a slice and not the entire input bytes array. The closest I've been able to get is the following:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract Test {
    function test1() public pure returns(string memory, bytes memory) {
        bytes6 _id = '123456';
        bytes memory b = 'The input _id is ______ and it was replaced using assembly';

        assembly {
            let dst := add(b, 49)
            mstore(dst, or(and(mload(dst), not(shl(208, 0x0000FFFF0000))), _id))
        }

        return (string(b), b);
    }

    function test2() public pure returns(string memory, bytes memory) {
        bytes6 _id = '123456';
        bytes memory b = 'The input _id is ______ and it was replaced using assembly';

        assembly {
            let dst := add(b, 49)
            mstore(dst, or(and(mload(dst), not(shl(224, 0xFFFF))), _id))
        }

        return (string(b), b);
    }
}
```

Both output the following:

```
"0": "string: The input _id is 34 and it was replaced using assembly"
```

But I want it to output:

```
"0": "string: The input _id is __34__ and it was replaced using assembly"
```

So you can see that the underscores were cleared out. I've tried playing around with _id and trying to mask it, although almost anything I try results in a out of gas error. Any help on this one would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going answer this as I found a solution. I based on it what was done in the slice method here: https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/blob/master/src/strings.sol, along with a combination of the prior post mentioned in the question.

```
    function test3() public pure returns(string memory, bytes memory) {
        bytes6 _id = '123456';
        bytes memory b = 'The input _id is ______ and it was replaced using assembly';


        assembly {
            let src := add(_id, 32)
            let dest := add(b, 49)

            let mask := shl(208, 0x0000FFFF0000)

            let srcpart := and(src, mask)
            // let srcpart := and(mload(src), mask) <--- causes out of gas
            let destpart := and(mload(dest), not(mask))

            mstore(dest, or(destpart, srcpart))
        }

        return (string(b), b);
    }
```

Outputs:

```
"0": "string: The input _id is __34__ and it was replaced using assembly"
```